# Could not connect the action: to target of class NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, macos

I will present to you a video of what I did to produce the error:

```
Could not connect the action registerUser: to target of class NSWindowController
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Video**: [Here is a quick video](http://bit.ly/PMKeYJ) of a screen recording to demonstrate what I did to create this problem that I'm having.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but I didn't see you set the object's class to your custom UserRegisterWC in interface builder

Comment: @jakev It's done automatically when you create an objective-c class along with a .xib view. Thanks for taking a look, I've got to be doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying `NSWindowController alloc` so you are getting an NSWindowController. But what you want is a UserRegistrationWC.

Comment: Just checked it, and yep that worked like a charm. Got rid of all my errors, and my IBActions responded to events now. Thank you

Comment: Your movie showed the whole thing, so it was easy to see where the problem was!

Comment: You understand the principle, right? As you rightly said in a different comment, your nib's File Owner is a UserRegistrationWC. This constitutes a promise that a UserRegistrationWC _will_ be the owner when this nib is loaded. But in your code, you were telling an NSWindowController to load the nib, thus violating that promise.